# javax.mail link missing Url parameters when clicked in Lotus Notes by a few clients

Tags: url, lotus-notes, jakarta-mail

An internal corporate application I am writing generates and sends an email.  In the content of the email I inline a link which has some url parameters.  The app sends the email to applicable co-workers and for debugging purposes, to myself as well.

When I get the email and hover over the link I see in the status bar at the bottom of Lotus Notes that the link has Url parameters.  So obvisouly when I click the link, IE opens and displays the query results as expected because the address has the Url parameters.

One co-worker (who sits accross town) complained that when they clicked the link, IE opened but the page displayed a message that that record could not be found.   I checked my log file and noticed that their log entry showed them accessing the base Url but without any Url parameters, hence why the record lookup failed.

How could this be? It is the same message sent to me.

Over the phone I asked them to hover over the link in Lotus and they said nothing shows in the status bar.  I then asked them to forward their email to me for further examination.  When I hover over the link in this email I see the Url in the status bar and it has Url parameters.

Whats is going on here?  Is there some preference in this co-workers Lotus that is stripping Url parameters off links that are clicked?

Checking the logs shows that most recipients when clicking this link are taken to the site with Url parameters still entact.  But there are a handfull other co-workers log entries which shows just the Url.

Comment: The answer to this could be related to the version and configuration of the recipient's Lotus Notes client, or it could be related to the user's settings in the Domino Directory for the preferred storage format of inbound mail along with the version of that user's Domino mail server. It's almost certainly not your code that's at fault, so I don't think that StackOverflow is the right forum for this, but then again I'm not sure if it fits on SuperUser or ServerFault either.

Comment: Since you mentioned that the link comes back to you intact when the user forwards the message back to you, I doubt the storage format is a problem.  I would look at the version, location document and preferences differences between this user and yourself and/or others for whom the link works properly.  I would also check to see if the user has any security software installed that might be altering the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix my problem. In the link url, I used "www.abc.com?data=date", which worked fine for a few years but recently Notes mail gets picky and decides to interpret that as "www.abc.com", ignoring "?data=data". I changed the url to "http://"www.abc.com?data=data", and Notes is all happy again.

The fix to my problem: add the "http://". Hope it helps others too.

Comment: I'll accept your answer to help with your reputation, even though it's my answer as a comment to your question below :)